# How to display a counting of an item from ListView

Tags: android

I would like to display a count inside a red circle that displays the news entries for that item. Like email count, know?

Is there anyway that i can do it or the best way is to create a new TextView and implement it?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a TextView with a background image like so:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/count"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/mybackground"/>
```

The background image is preferably a 9-patch drawable (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) or it could be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>

</shape>
```

This one would draw a red rectangle with rounded corners but you can create any shape you like (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

If you don't want the text to be centered (like at the right bottom corner) you have two options:

**Option 1**

Make the TextView larger than it would be when just wrapping around the text (which is the default). So either use match_parent for android:layout_width and android:layout_height or set an absolute size (in dp). Also use the gravity parameter to position it at the right bottom corner:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/count"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:gravity="right|bottom"
     android:background="@drawable/mybackground"/>
```

**Option 2**

Use padding to move the text in the direction you need it to move:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybackground"/>
```

Using two views on top of each other is of course possible too but inefficient. You'd need at least an extra ViewGroup (e.g. FrameLayout) around the TextView (for the counter) and the ImageView (for the background) to make sure they are positioned above each other, meaning you'd replace one TextView by three other views. Also  you'd still have to set the size of the enclosing ViewGroup to something bigger than the TextView so there's nothing gained with that solution.

Comment: I was trying to avoid create a TextView. Do you know if can i put a TextView above an Image or another TextView? Example: i have an image and i would like to put this TextView inside ( above ) the image, align on right bottom of the image. Is it possible?

Comment: So you're one of those people who change the requirements during the development process, haven't we all seen that one before? ;-). Anyway I changed my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: Haha no, buddy! i'm new on android and i was wondering if had another solution instead a textview but if this is the way, here we go ..and thank you for the answers/explanation :)

Comment: An important rule for Android layouts is to keep them as simple as possible. The fewer views it has to render the better the performance (important especially for collection views like lists or grid views). If you can do it with a simple TextView then go for it. There's no simpler and more efficient solution.